# How to stop jQuery animation from firing several times

Tags: jquery, animation

My jQuery animation fires multiple times consecutively every time the cursor enters the element, since I have the animation to run on `mouseenter`. But that's causing some problems, since if the user enters his cursor quickly and repeatedly, the animation will fire many times after the cursor has left even though the cursor is long-gone. This is an example of an animation I have that's facing this problem.

```
// JS

$(".nav a").mouseenter(function(){
    if ($(this).width() === '150') {
        $(this).stop().animate({
            backgroundColor: 'white',
            color: 'black',
            width: '+=20px',
        });
    };
});

$(".nav a").mouseleave(function () {
    if ($(this).width() === '170') {
        $(this).delay(300).animate({
            backgroundColor: 'transparent',
            color: 'white',
            width: '-=20px',
        });
    };
});



// HTML

 <div class="nav">
        <div class="nav bar">
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                <li><a href="home.html">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="About.html">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="Contact.html">Get in touch</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
</div>


//CSS

.nav{
     width: 1330px;
     padding: 0.5%;
}


.nav a{
     font-size: 20px;
     color: white;
     width: 150px;
}
```

I've seen other questions about this problem, and using the `stop()` function has been suggested, but how exactly do I use that to tackle my problem?

Comment: This is one of the cases where a fiddle can be very helpful.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/tb0hj9ty/ This is my fiddle @Django; observe how the width keeps on going wider and narrower after repeated 'mouseenter's

Comment: See the solution I've just posted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this approach:

```
$(".nav a").mouseenter(function(){
        $(this).stop( true ).animate({
            backgroundColor: 'white',
            color: 'black',
            'margin-right': '20px'
        });
});

$(".nav a").mouseleave(function () {
        $(this).stop( true ).delay(300).animate({
            backgroundColor: 'transparent',
            color: 'white',
            'margin-right': '0'
        });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/tb0hj9ty/2/

Comment: Thank you very much! Been dealing with this problem for over a year now! It works perfectly fine now!

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".nav a").mouseenter(function(){
    $(this).stop().animate({
        backgroundColor: 'white',
        color: 'black',
        width: '+=20px',
    });

});

$(".nav a").mouseleave(function(){
    $(this).stop().animate({
        backgroundColor: 'transparent',
        color: 'white',
        width: '-=20px',
    });
});
```

Stop the animation if any on the element, and then, trigger the animation in your case.

Another approach:

```
// Assuming that initial element width is 500

$(".nav a").mouseenter(function(){
    if ($(this).width() === '500') {
        $(this).stop().animate({
            backgroundColor: 'white',
            color: 'black',
            width: '+=20px'
        });
    }
}).mouseleave(function () {
    if ($(this).width() === '520') {
        $(this).delay(300).animate({
            backgroundColor: 'transparent',
            color: 'white',
            width: '-=20px',
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you, but this leads to another problem, incomplete 'mouseenters' are causing the buttons to grow shorter by 20px, as perhaps the incomplete 'mouseenters' are being counted as 'mouseleaves'?

Comment: @MullerA added another approach

Comment: This has the same problem and still fires repeatedly after many 'mouseenters'.

Comment: update approach again. this should work in that case. We restrict the mouse enter animation only when the element has its initial width. and shrink only when it achieved that particular width. it will be great if you can post the html as well with css if any.

Answer (score 0):

I have an idea !  you can use a variable, say `animate_happened` to tell jquery start new animation  only if this variable is `false` :

```
 var animation_happened = flase;
   if(animation_happened == flase){
           $(".nav a").mouseenter(function(){
        if ($(this).width() === '150') {
            animation_happened = true;
            $(this).stop().animate({
                backgroundColor: 'white',
                color: 'black',
                width: '+=20px',
            });
        };
    });
   }


$(".nav a").mouseleave(function () {
    if ($(this).width() === '170') {
        animation_happened = false;     
        $(this).delay(300).animate({
            backgroundColor: 'transparent',
            color: 'white',
            width: '-=20px',
        });
    };
});
```

now only if one animation completes its cycle, new animation happens!

Comment: That crashed my whole jQuery code! Needless to say; it didn't work...Please check out my fiddle above.